# How to convert sun.misc.BASE64Encoder to org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons-codec

I have the following code for `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] saltArray = decoder.decodeBuffer(saltD);
byte[] ciphertextArray = decoder.decodeBuffer(ciphertext);
```

and would like to convert it to `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`. I've gone through the APIs, the docs, etc., but I can't find something that seems to match and give the same resulting values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually almost the exact same:

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] saltArray = decoder.decode(saltD);
byte[] ciphertextArray = decoder.decode(ciphertext);
```

For decoding:

```
String saltString = encoder.encodeToString(salt);
String ciphertextString = encoder.encodeToString(ciphertext);
```

This last one was tougher because you use "toString" at the end.

Comment: Why am I getting `The method encodeToString(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64`?

Comment: This method is only available starting from commons-codec-1.4

Answer (score 9):

You can use [decodeBase64(byte[] base64Data)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28byte%5B%5D%29) or [decodeBase64(String base64String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) methods. For example:

```
byte[] result = Base64.decodeBase64(base64);
```

Here is a short example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

public class TestCodec {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String test = "Test BASE64Encoder vs Base64";

//      String encoded = new BASE64Encoder().encode(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//      byte[] result = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encoded);

        byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] result = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);

        System.out.println(new String(result, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the salt? This is a key part that I can't seem to get working.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of these two class(import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder; import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder), you can use **java.util.Base64** class.Now change encode and decode method as below.
For encoding :

```
String ciphertextString =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext);
```

For decoding:

```
  final byte[] encryptedByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(ciphertext);
```

Here ciphertext is the encoded password in encoding method .

Now everything is done, you can save your program and run. It will run without showing any error.